# rabbitConnectionFactory autodetected for JMX exposure

Tags: spring-boot, rabbitmq, spring-amqp

I have a Spring Boot application that supports Kafka.  Recently I am trying to make it also support RabbitMQ.  I set up the code using the `@Profile` annotation so that all the new code for RabbitMQ should be active only if I select `spring.profiles.active` to be `rabbit-mq`.  Likewise, the Kafka-specific code are marked out by profile value of `kafka`

I was surprise to see that even with the above setup, when I set the profile to be `kafka`, some RabbitMQ is still included and activated, through a mechanism **JMX exposure**.  Specifically, a `rabbitConnectionFactory` bean was constructed, and then it tried to do health check with a RabbitMQ broker at `localhost:5672`, and failed.

In the log file, I saw these messages:

```
... o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Registering beans for JMX exposure on startup
... o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Bean with name 'rabbitConnectionFactory' has been autodetected for JMX exposure
... o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Located managed bean 'rabbitConnectionFactory': registering with JMX server as MBean [org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection:name=rabbitConnectionFactory,type=CachingConnectionFactory]
... o.s.c.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor  : Starting beans in phase 2147483547
... o.s.c.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor  : Starting beans in phase 2147483647
... o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
... c.s.datacomparatorproducer.Application   : Started Application in 5.175 seconds (JVM running for 5.663)
... o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
... o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization started
... o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization completed in 15 ms
... o.s.a.r.c.CachingConnectionFactory       : Attempting to connect to: [localhost:5672]
... o.s.b.a.amqp.RabbitHealthIndicator       : Rabbit health check failed

org.springframework.amqp.AmqpConnectException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.support.RabbitExceptionTranslator.convertRabbitAccessException(RabbitExceptionTranslator.java:62) ~[spring-rabbit-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.AbstractConnectionFactory.createBareConnection(AbstractConnectionFactory.java:476) ~[spring-rabbit-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory.createConnection(CachingConnectionFactory.java:614) ~[spring-rabbit-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.ConnectionFactoryUtils.createConnection(ConnectionFactoryUtils.java:240) ~[spring-rabbit-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.doExecute(RabbitTemplate.java:1797) ~[spring-rabbit-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.execute(RabbitTemplate.java:1771) ~[spring-rabbit-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.3.RELEASE]
```

I have two questions:

1. How can I avoid RabbitMQ code from being included?  Why my set up using `@Profile` did not work as expected?
2. How do I configure the `rabbitConnectionFactory`? Currently it is trying to talk to `localhost:5672`.  I know how to, in general, set up Spring template to use `application-xxx.properties` for `spring.rabbitmq.{host,port}`, but in this case, since the code is auto-included, I don't know how to configure `rabbitConnectionFactory`

**Usual configuration**

```
spring.rabbitmq.host=someRabbitBroker
spring.rabbitmq.port=5672
```

**Update**

**Attempt 1: Excluding `RabbitAutoConfiguration`**

Thank you Gary Russell for the suggestion.  I tried his method and changed my `@SpringBootApplication` as follows.  The idea here is to exclude `RabbitAutoConfiguration` when `spring.rabbitmq.host` is NOT defined (when the profile of `rabbit-mq` is not active):

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    @ConditionalOnProperty(value="spring.rabbitmq.host")
    @Bean 
    RabbitAutoConfiguration rabbitAutoConfiguration(){
        return new RabbitAutoConfiguration();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

I am not sure if this code is the correct way to do it, but it did not work.  When my app started, I still saw these in the message:

```
... o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Registering beans for JMX exposure on startup
... o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Bean with name 'rabbitConnectionFactory' has been autodetected for JMX exposure
... o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Located managed bean 'rabbitConnectionFactory': registering with JMX server as MBean [org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection:name=rabbitConnectionFactory,type=CachingConnectionFactory]
... o.s.c.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor  : Starting beans in phase 2147483547
```

I am okay with having the bean constructed, as long as I can stop it from doing health check (or at least configure it to use my designated host and port).  Is there a way to do this?

Comment: For my second question ... as a hack I can put those lines for `spring.rabbitmq.{host,port}` into the file `application-kafka.properties` and they would be taken.  But obviously this is a dirty hack and I would like to know about a proper solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You either need to exclude the spring-rabbit jar from the classpath or disable rabbitmq auto-configuration by excluding `RabbitAutoConfiguration` from the `@SpringBootApplication`.

**Update: disabling health check**

See the [boot properties documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.4.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#common-application-properties). Specifically set `management.health.rabbit.enabled` to `false`

Comment: Thanks Gary Russell for your suggestion.  I tried your second method -- excluding `RabbitAutoConfiguration`, but it did not work.  I put the code in the updated question above.  Can you review if I have coded it correctly?  Or, as I said, is there a way that I just stop `rabbitConnectionFactory` from doing health check?

Comment: See the [boot properties documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.4.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#common-application-properties). Specifically set `management.health.rabbit.enabled` to `false`.

Comment: Yes it works like a charm.  Thanks a lot!  I have updated your answer and accepted it.  You have save my day!